# Tag Item programmatically

Tags: articles, tags

I am trying to tag some items (com_content.article) programmatically, and I have an issue while trying to use the **TagsHelper** class' **tagItem** method. I am not an expert in Joomla and I am a bit lost.

I get the following error (below the call stack):

> `1048 Column 'type_alias' cannot be null`

It seems that the helper does not manage to get the type_alias (which should be com_content.article) from my $table object... Does anyone see how I could help it?

Here is my code:

```
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
use Joomla\CMS\Table\Table;
use Joomla\CMS\Helper\TagsHelper;

[...]

$helpertags = new TagsHelper();
$table = Table::getInstance('Content', 'JTable', array());
$table->load($id_article);
$tags = array( 321, 43 ); // IDs of some tags I created or checked before
$helpertags->tagItem('com_content.article', $table, $tags, false);
$table->store();
```

```
1   ()  JROOT/libraries/vendor/joomla/database/src/Mysqli/MysqliStatement.php:435

2   Joomla\Database\Mysqli\MysqliStatement->execute()   JROOT/libraries/vendor/joomla/database/src/DatabaseDriver.php:675

3   Joomla\Database\DatabaseDriver->execute()   JROOT/libraries/src/Helper/TagsHelper.php:126

4   Joomla\CMS\Helper\TagsHelper->addTagMapping()   JROOT/libraries/src/Helper/TagsHelper.php:1043

5   Joomla\CMS\Helper\TagsHelper->tagItem()     JROOT/administrator/components/com_jsonems/tmpl/hello/default.php:151
```

Comment: Version Joomla 3 or 4?

Comment: Version Joomla 4.2.6

Answer (score 2):

**The shortest possible working version** of this code is this as I tested this:

```
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
use Joomla\CMS\Helper\TagsHelper;

function addTagsToArticle($ucmId, $articleId, $tags) {

    $tagsHelper = new TagsHelper();

    $app = Factory::getApplication();
    $factory = $app->bootComponent('com_content')->getMVCFactory();

    $table = $factory->createTable('Article', 'Table');
    
    $table->load($articleId);

    $tagsHelper->typeAlias = $table->typeAlias;

    $tagsHelper->tagItem($ucmId, $table, $tags, false);

}
```

And you call this function like:

```
$newTags = ['#new#Millions', '#new#Worldwide'];

$ucmId = 5; // core_content_id of the article from ucm_content table

$itemID = 11; // article ID in #__content table

addTagsToArticle($ucmId, $itemID, $newTags);
```

This way the code works and save new tags to an article. without the `store()` method at the end, it is not needed, and the tags has to be with `#new#` prefix in the array.

**THE LONG WAY OF DOING THE SAME**

I have tested some codes more deeply regarding tagging content items **in Joomla 4**. I am not sure that too many people want to tag articles/content programmatically and I do not think that there is any official way of doing that but this is one way of doing that. Someone really worked out a quite good and complex tagging system for Joomla and I just took some parts from that core code and you can use it in your own custom methods.

First I created a function `createNewTags()` using the Joomla4 core `createTagsFromField()` from the `TagsHelper` class. I used that because it is not worthy to create similar function and it is sure that it works well on saving new tags. If a tag was already in the tag table, then it does not save it again. However, we have to modify the core `addTagMapping()` method for our custom code.

```
use Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper;
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
use Joomla\CMS\Helper\TagsHelper;
use Joomla\CMS\UCM\UCMType;
use Joomla\Database\DatabaseDriver;
use Joomla\Database\ParameterType;
use Joomla\Utilities\ArrayHelper;

/**
* create new tags by array of strings (texts)
* @param   array    $tags   Array of tags to be applied. 
*
* @return  array  -- created tags
*/

function createNewTags($tags = []) {

    $tagsHelper = new TagsHelper();

    $new_tags = array_map(fn($tag) => "#new#$tag", $tags);

    // create tags first and save it
    $tags_ids = $tagsHelper->createTagsFromField($new_tags);

    return $tags_ids;
}

// we have to create our own custom function for mapping
function addTagMapping($ucmId, $contentId, $table, $tags = [])
{
    $db = $table->getDbo();
    $item = $contentId;
    $ucm = new UCMType($table->typeAlias, $db);
    $typeId = $ucm->getTypeId();

    // Prevent saving duplicate tags
    $tags = array_values(array_unique($tags));

    if (!$tags) {
        return true;
    }

    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->insert('#__contentitem_tag_map');
    $query->columns(
        [
            $db->quoteName('core_content_id'),
            $db->quoteName('content_item_id'),
            $db->quoteName('tag_id'),
            $db->quoteName('type_id'),
            $db->quoteName('type_alias'),
            $db->quoteName('tag_date'),
        ]
    );

    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        $query->values(
            implode(
                ',',
                array_merge(
                    $query->bindArray([(int) $ucmId, (int) $item, (int) $tag, (int) $typeId]),
                    $query->bindArray([$table->typeAlias], ParameterType::STRING),
                    [$query->currentTimestamp()]
                )
            )
        );
    }

    $db->setQuery($query);

    return (bool) $db->execute();
}

function tagThoseArticleItems($ucmId, $itemID, $ourTags = [], $replace = true) {

    $tagsHelper = new TagsHelper();  
    $tags = $tagsHelper->createNewTags($ourTags);

    $app = Factory::getApplication();
    $factory = $app->bootComponent('com_content')->getMVCFactory();

    $table = $factory->createTable('Article', 'Table');    
    
    $tagsHelper->typeAlias = $table->typeAlias;
    // $table->setTagsHelper($tagsHelper); // only if the table does not have it

    foreach ($tags as $tagId) {
        $tagsHelper->tagDeleteInstances($tagId);
    }
    
    // we have to use our own custom function on this
    // with added itemID (content item ID) to the call
    $result = addTagMapping($ucmId, $itemID, $table, $tags, $replace = true);

    return $result;
    
}
```

And you call this whole thing like:

```
$ourTags = ['getty', 'Roma', 'New York'];

// this is an existing article ID from the #__ucm_content table
$ucmId = 5;

$itemID = 11; // The article ID in #__content table

$our_tags_created = tagThoseArticleItems($ucmId, $itemID, $ourTags, $replace = true);
```

The second function is just doing the tag mapping correctly. **I hardcoded the content Table** in this, but you can refactor this for using other tables too, if not content tagging.

**Important to note** that `$ucmId` is the `core_content_id` from the `#__ucm_content` table. so you should use that ID as the first argument and NOT a type like `com_content.article` and **not the article ID** from the `#__content table`. In our custom code we have to provide the article ID too from the content table.

**The challenge**

I tried but I have not found a short, straightforward solution on this task in Joomla on tagging content articles from an outside extension for example. Anybody else on this? The question is interesting because if someone came with a Wordpress developer background, rightfully would ask and look for a one line solution on this, like WP has on tagging a Post:

`wp_set_post_tags( int $post_id, string|array $tags = '', bool $append = false )`

Unfortunately at many of these small points we could realize the big difference on developer friendliness of the Content Management Systems.

Comment: Thank you very much for your complete answer. I made several tests and ended up with similar issues. My final option was to directly register the tag association in the DB. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The error message "Column 'type_alias' cannot be null" suggests that the type_alias field in the #__content_types table is not being set correctly when you are trying to tag the content item.

To fix this issue, you can try setting the type_alias field of your $table object explicitly before calling the tagItem() method. You can set the type_alias field to 'com_content.article' which is the expected value for this type of content item.

Here is how you can modify your code to set the type_alias field:

```
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
use Joomla\CMS\Table\Table;
use Joomla\CMS\Helper\TagsHelper;

[...]

$helpertags = new TagsHelper();
$table = Table::getInstance('Content', 'JTable', array());
$table->load($id_article);
$table->type_alias = 'com_content.article'; // set the type_alias field
$tags = array( 321, 43 ); // IDs of some tags I created or checked before
$helpertags->tagItem('com_content.article',$table,$tags, false);
$table->store();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried this before, but it does not make a difference...