# Adding a Tag to an Article (in PHP)

Tags: php, joomla-4.x, tags

In J4, when I want to set a value to a Custom Field, I use the following code and it works fine:

```
$model = new FieldModel(array('ignore_request' => true));
$model->setFieldValue(2, $item->id, 'blabla'); // where 2 is the CF ID
```

I also need to *add*  Tag with ID 2 to that same Article (without losing the existing Tag).

Comment: I just wrote about this subject at this question's answer: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/32870/tag-item-programmatically  - Probably you can take some useful info from that.